# Why haven't I got "Scripts" in Python27 on Windows?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have installed Python2.7 on Windows. I tried to install pip, so I downloaded get-pip, then I run it but it didn't install anything in "scripts" in python27, neither in Python27/Tools/Scripts

Comment: Consider adding `C:\python27\scripts` folder in PATH variable. For better visualisation watch this video https://youtu.be/zPMr0lEMqpo

Comment: I haven't got that folder in C:\python27 !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem:

When I have tried to run get-pip, I have right-clicked on the file get-pip.py and I have chosen "Python Launcher for Windows" to run it. Instead, I should have opened the command prompt in the right folder and I should have written "python get-pip.py".